# Is it safe to remove old Ubuntu 4.x kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64, fully patched with `dist-upgrade`. I have an old kernel and I am not sure if it safe to remove:

```
$ ls /boot/
config-4.15.0-64-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-5.0.0-29-generic       memtest86+_multiboot.bin
efi                           System.map-4.15.0-64-generic
grub                          System.map-5.0.0-29-generic
initrd.img-4.15.0-64-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-64-generic
initrd.img-5.0.0-29-generic   vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-generic
memtest86+.bin
```

I also have Nvidia and Virtual Box DKMS's in `/usr/lib` for the kernels. I  used `dkms remove ...` to remove the 4.x modules, but they keep returning:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/
4.15.0-64-generic  5.0.0-29-generic

$ dkms status
nvidia, 430.26, 4.15.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 430.26, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.2.32, 4.15.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.2.32, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I'm catching random crashes and I believe they are due to video drivers. Each boot and each login generates a Crash Report (not a panic). The crash happens with both Nouveau (generic X driver) and Nvidia (nvidia-driver-430). Unfortunately, Ubuntu does not provide the details. I am only offered the choice to Cancel or Send (and not View).

I'd like to remove the old kernel in hopes of clearing the issue. The rub is, the last time I tired to do it with SecureBoot on and signed kernels, the machine stooped booting.

My question is, is it safe to remove old Ubuntu 4.x kernel in this configuration?

Comment: That its not booting if you removed the old kernel is strange. It ought to be safe - ubuntu does remove some old kernels automatically, That said, if you're booted into the new kernel, and its crashing, the issue ought to be with the new, not old kernel

Answer (score 0):

The only kernel you *need* is the one be you are booting to. Old kernels and even newer kernels are always safe to delete.